# Bootstrap 4 card-deck with number of columns based on viewport

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-4, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to implement the card-deck feature in bootstrap 4 to make all of my cards the same height.

The examples that bootstrap provides show 4 nice cards, but it's 4 cards on the row, no matter the viewport. See the codeply [here](http://www.codeply.com/render/KrUO8QpyXP).

This doesn't make sense to me since, I would assume, that you'd want a minimum size for your card to shrink to in order for your content to still look good.

I then tried adding in some viewport classes to break on screen sizes, but as soon as that div gets added, the card-deck doesn't apply anymore, thus not making the cards equal height.

How can I get this accomplished? Is this a missing feature that will be addressed in the full release of Bootstrap 4?

Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/crrm5q9m/

```
<div class="card-deck-wrapper">
  <div class="card-deck">
    <div class="card card-inverse card-success text-center col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 col-xl-1">
      <div class="card-block">
        <blockquote class="card-blockquote">
          <p>It's really good news that the new Bootstrap 4 now has support for CSS 3 flexbox.</p>
          <footer>Makes flexible layouts <cite title="Source Title">Faster</cite></footer>
        </blockquote>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card card-inverse card-danger text-center col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 col-xl-1">
      <div class="card-block">
        <blockquote class="card-blockquote">
          <p>The Bootstrap 3.x element that was called "Panel" before, is now called a "Card".</p>
          <footer>All of this makes more <cite title="Source Title">Sense</cite></footer>
        </blockquote>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card card-inverse card-warning text-center col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 col-xl-1">
      <div class="card-block">
        <blockquote class="card-blockquote">
          <p>There are also some interesting new text classes for uppercase and capitalize.</p>
          <footer>These handy utilities make it <cite title="Source Title">Easy</cite></footer>
        </blockquote>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card card-inverse card-info text-center col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 col-xl-1">
      <div class="card-block">
        <blockquote class="card-blockquote">
          <p>If you want to use cool icons in Bootstrap 4, you'll have to find your own such as Font Awesome or Ionicons.</p>
          <footer>The Glyphicons are not <cite title="Source Title">Included</cite></footer>
        </blockquote>
      </div>
    </div>
        <div class="card card-inverse card-success text-center col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 col-xl-1">
      <div class="card-block">
        <blockquote class="card-blockquote">
          <p>It's really good news that the new Bootstrap 4 now has support for CSS 3 flexbox.</p>
          <footer>Makes flexible layouts <cite title="Source Title">Faster</cite></footer>
        </blockquote>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card card-inverse card-danger text-center col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 col-xl-1">
      <div class="card-block">
        <blockquote class="card-blockquote">
          <p>The Bootstrap 3.x element that was called "Panel" before, is now called a "Card".</p>
          <footer>All of this makes more <cite title="Source Title">Sense</cite></footer>
        </blockquote>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card card-inverse card-warning text-center col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 col-xl-1">
      <div class="card-block">
        <blockquote class="card-blockquote">
          <p>There are also some interesting new text classes for uppercase and capitalize.</p>
          <footer>These handy utilities make it <cite title="Source Title">Easy</cite></footer>
        </blockquote>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card card-inverse card-info text-center col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 col-xl-1">
      <div class="card-block">
        <blockquote class="card-blockquote">
          <p>If you want to use cool icons in Bootstrap 4, you'll have to find your own such as Font Awesome or Ionicons.</p>
          <footer>The Glyphicons are not <cite title="Source Title">Included</cite></footer>
        </blockquote>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://www.codeply.com/go/AP1MpYKY2H/bootstrap-4-card-deck-columns-per-row

Answer (score 81, accepted):

***Updated 2018***

If you want a [**responsive card-deck**](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/card/#card-decks), use the visibility utils to force a wrap every X columns on different viewport width(breakpoints)...

[Bootstrap 4 responsive **card-deck**](http://www.codeply.com/go/nIB6oSbv6q) (v **4.1**)

---

Original answer for Bootstrap 4 alpha 2:

You can **use the grid `col-*-*` to get the different widths** (instead of card-deck) and then set equal height to the cols using flexbox.

```
.row > div[class*='col-'] {
  display: flex;
  flex:1 0 auto;
}
```

http://codeply.com/go/O0KdSG2YX2 (alpha 2)

The problem is that w/o flexbox enabled the `card-deck` uses `table-cell` where it becomes very hard to control the width. As of Bootstrap 4 Alpha 6, flexbox is default so the additional CSS is not required for flexbox, and the **`h-100` class can be used to make the cards full height**: http://www.codeply.com/go/gnOzxd4Spk

---

**Related question:** 
[Bootstrap 4 - Responsive cards in card-columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34140793/bootstrap-4-responsive-cards-in-card-columns)

Comment: I forgot, is flexbox enabled by default in Bootstrap 4?

Comment: Gotcha, was wondering why it wasn't working in my fiddle. I'll have to play with it when I get home so I can turn on flexbox...

Comment: Any idea how to make cards in the last row having the same widths as any other rows?

Comment: I started with this answer and it was complicated to make a dynamic layout like this.  Better to use `.row` and `.col` classes for responsive.  See answer below.

Comment: My answer already said to use the grid col instead of a card-deck

Comment: I ran into some weirdness where the cards wouldn't wrap properly with the `div`s in the example.  Getting rid of the `w-100` fixed it for me.
using bootstrap4.1.3 on Chrome

Comment: Where in your example are you using the util class to specify the column count? I don't see it...

Comment: Look at https://codeply.com/go/nIB6oSbv6q and look at the empty spacer divs that are used intermittently between the cards - e.g. `<div class="w-100 d-none d-sm-block d-md-none"><!-- wrap every 2 on sm--></div>`

Answer (score 48):

Here's a solution with Sass to configure the number of cards per line depending on breakpoints: https://codepen.io/migli/pen/OQVRMw

It works fine with Bootstrap 4 beta 3

```
// Bootstrap 4 breakpoints & gutter
$grid-breakpoints: (
    xs: 0,
    sm: 576px,
    md: 768px,
    lg: 992px,
    xl: 1200px
) !default;

$grid-gutter-width: 30px !default;

// number of cards per line for each breakpoint
$cards-per-line: (
    xs: 1,
    sm: 2,
    md: 3,
    lg: 4,
    xl: 5
);

@each $name, $breakpoint in $grid-breakpoints {
    @media (min-width: $breakpoint) {
        .card-deck .card {
            flex: 0 0 calc(#{100/map-get($cards-per-line, $name)}% - #{$grid-gutter-width});
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT (2019/10)**

I worked on another solution which uses **horizontal lists group + flex utilities** instead of card-deck:

https://codepen.io/migli/pen/gOOmYLb

It's an easy solution to organize any kind of elements into responsive grid

```html
<div class="container">
    <ul class="list-group list-group-horizontal align-items-stretch flex-wrap">
        <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
        <!--= add as many items as you need  =-->
    </ul>
</div>
```

```css
.list-group-item {
    width: 95%;
    margin: 1% !important;
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {
    .list-group-item {
        width: 47%;
        margin: 5px 1.5% !important;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .list-group-item {
        width: 31.333%;
        margin: 5px 1% !important;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .list-group-item {
        width: 23%;
        margin: 5px 1% !important;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .list-group-item {
        width: 19%;
        margin: 5px .5% !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: @trainoasis It didn't break anything for me. See the CodePen link in the answer: https://codepen.io/migli/pen/OQVRMw. When I change $cards-per-line, the number of cards changes accordingly.

Comment: I see, ty. Perhaps I have too much custom CSS already and there's a conflict somewhere. Will try to find it .

Comment: It works like a charm, also with bootstrap v 4.1.1. Thank you.

Comment: Works fine everywhere except IE 11. Any solution?

Comment: IE is definitely dead

Comment: On the Cards Layout documentation appears this message: "these layout options are not yet responsive." It maybe not a good idea to use them yet

Comment: That's exactly why I proposed this solution - they're now responsive.

Comment: Yes, @migli, but my project is basically for government use, they still like to use windows 7 and IE. Bootstrap 4.1 rescued me with same height columns and h-100 class.

Comment: Governments are always at the forefront of technology!

Comment: This is a great and clever solution, it works like a charm for me.

HOWEVER I can't seem to keep a minimum of 2 cards per row on xs screens (using bootstrap 4). Any ideas?

Comment: The default responsive Bootstrap card columns start at 576px:

(at)media (min-width: 576px)
.card-deck {
    -ms-flex-flow: row wrap;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    margin-right: -15px;
    margin-left: -15px;
}

Replace with 
(at)media (min-width: 0) and set $cards-per-line to 2 for xs

This way it'll be ok

Comment: I suggest using `$card-deck-margin` instead of `$grid-gutter-width`: `flex: 0 0 calc(#{100/map-get($cards-per-line, $name)}% - #{$card-deck-margin * 2});`

Comment: best solution for me using bootstrap-vue which is still on 4.3.x

Answer (score 47):

I got this to work by adding a `min-width` to the cards:

```
<div class="card mb-3" style="min-width: 18rem;">
  <p>Card content</p>
</div>
```

The cards don't go below this width, but still properly fill each row and have equal heights.

Comment: Great solution to a significant issue in Bootstrap

Comment: I also put "...max-width: 22rem;" to avoid too wide cards on new line

Comment: This worked perfectly without having to create crazy tag conditions on django templates

Comment: this is one of the best solutions, neat and effective

Answer (score 7):

I've used CSS Grid to fix that.
CSS Grid will make all the elements in the same row, all the same height.

I haven't looked into making all the elements in all the rows the same height though.

Anyway, here's how it can be done:

HTML:

```
<div class="grid-container">

  <div class="card">...</div>
  <div class="card">...</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.grid-container {
  display: grid;  
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 1fr));
}
```

Here's a complete JSFiddle.
https://jsfiddle.net/bluegrounds/owjvhstq/4/

Answer (score 6):

```
<div class="w-100 d-lg-none mt-4"></div>
```

I created 4 cards and place this code between second and third card, try this.

Comment: Nice solution, but to make it work you'll need to remove `d-lg-none` class, so it woud be `<div class="w-100 mt-4"></div>`

Answer (score 5):

**This answer is for those who are using Bootstrap 4.1+ and for those who care about IE 11 as well**

Card-deck does not adapt the number visible of cards according to the viewport size.

Above methods work but do not support IE. With the below method, you can achieve similar functionality and responsive cards.

You can manage the number of cards to show/hide in different breakpoints.

In Bootstrap 4.1+ columns are same height by default, just make sure your card/content uses all available space.
Run the snippet, you'll understand

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4 mb-3">
            <div class="card mb-3 h-100">

                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                    <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4 mb-3">
            <div class="card mb-3 h-100">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                    <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4 mb-3">
            <div class="card mb-3 h-100">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                    <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Question required the use of CardDeck

Comment: Yes @IanWarner. I used CardDeck with updates suggested in the above answers, but for my luck, I had to support IE and nothing seemed to work, I solved it using this method.

Answer (score 3):

Define columns by min width based on viewport:

```css
    /* Number of Cards by Row based on Viewport */
    @media (min-width: 576px) {
        .card-deck .card {
            min-width: 50.1%; /* 1 Column */
            margin-bottom: 12px;
        }
    }

    @media (min-width: 768px) {
        .card-deck .card {
            min-width: 33.4%;  /* 2 Columns */
        }
    }

    @media (min-width: 992px) {
        .card-deck .card {
            min-width: 25.1%;  /* 3 Columns */
        }
    }

    @media (min-width: 1200px) {
        .card-deck .card {
            min-width: 20.1%;  /* 4 Columns */
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is a great solution.

Answer (score 2):

Using Bootstrap 4.4.1, I was able to set the number of cards per deck using simple classes by adding some scss into the mix.

### HTML

```
<div class="card-deck deck-1 deck-md-2 deck-lg-3">
   <div class="card">
      <h2 class="card-header">Card 1</h3>
      <div class="card-body">
          Card body
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer">
          Card footer
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="card">
      <h2 class="card-header">Card 2</h3>
      <div class="card-body">
          Card body
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer">
          Card footer
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="card">
      <h2 class="card-header">Card 3</h3>
      <div class="card-body">
          Card body
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer">
          Card footer
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

### SCSS

```
// _card_deck_columns.scss
// add deck-X and deck-BP-X classes to select the number of cards per line
@for $i from 1 through $grid-columns {
  .deck-#{$i} > .card {
    $percentage: percentage(1 / $i);
    @if $i == 1 {
      $width: $percentage;
      flex-basis: $width;
      max-width: $width;
      margin-left: 0;
      margin-right: 0;
    } @else {
      $width: unquote("calc(#{$percentage} - #{$grid-gutter-width})");
      flex-basis: $width;
      max-width: $width;
    }
  }
}
@each $breakpoint in map-keys($grid-breakpoints) {
  $infix: breakpoint-infix($breakpoint, $grid-breakpoints);
  @include media-breakpoint-up($breakpoint) {
    @for $i from 1 through $grid-columns {
      .deck#{$infix}-#{$i} > .card {
        $percentage: percentage(1 / $i);
        @if $i == 1 {
          $width: $percentage;
          flex-basis: $width;
          max-width: $width;
          margin-left: 0;
          margin-right: 0;
        } @else {
          $width: unquote("calc(#{$percentage} - #{$grid-gutter-width})");
          flex-basis: $width;
          max-width: $width;
          margin-left: $grid-gutter-width / 2;
          margin-right: $grid-gutter-width / 2;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### CSS

```
.deck-1 > .card {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0; }

.deck-2 > .card {
  flex-basis: calc(50% - 30px);
  max-width: calc(50% - 30px); }

.deck-3 > .card {
  flex-basis: calc(33.3333333333% - 30px);
  max-width: calc(33.3333333333% - 30px); }

.deck-4 > .card {
  flex-basis: calc(25% - 30px);
  max-width: calc(25% - 30px); }

.deck-5 > .card {
  flex-basis: calc(20% - 30px);
  max-width: calc(20% - 30px); }

.deck-6 > .card {
  flex-basis: calc(16.6666666667% - 30px);
  max-width: calc(16.6666666667% - 30px); }

.deck-7 > .card {
  flex-basis: calc(14.2857142857% - 30px);
  max-width: calc(14.2857142857% - 30px); }

.deck-8 > .card {
  flex-basis: calc(12.5% - 30px);
  max-width: calc(12.5% - 30px); }

.deck-9 > .card {
  flex-basis: calc(11.1111111111% - 30px);
  max-width: calc(11.1111111111% - 30px); }

.deck-10 > .card {
  flex-basis: calc(10% - 30px);
  max-width: calc(10% - 30px); }

.deck-11 > .card {
  flex-basis: calc(9.0909090909% - 30px);
  max-width: calc(9.0909090909% - 30px); }

.deck-12 > .card {
  flex-basis: calc(8.3333333333% - 30px);
  max-width: calc(8.3333333333% - 30px); }

.deck-1 > .card {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0; }

.deck-2 > .card {
  flex-basis: calc(50% - 30px);
  max-width: calc(50% - 30px);
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-right: 15px; }

.deck-3 > .card {
  flex-basis: calc(33.3333333333% - 30px);
  max-width: calc(33.3333333333% - 30px);
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-right: 15px; }

.deck-4 > .card {
  flex-basis: calc(25% - 30px);
  max-width: calc(25% - 30px);
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-right: 15px; }

.deck-5 > .card {
  flex-basis: calc(20% - 30px);
  max-width: calc(20% - 30px);
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-right: 15px; }

.deck-6 > .card {
  flex-basis: calc(16.6666666667% - 30px);
  max-width: calc(16.6666666667% - 30px);
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-right: 15px; }

.deck-7 > .card {
  flex-basis: calc(14.2857142857% - 30px);
  max-width: calc(14.2857142857% - 30px);
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-right: 15px; }

.deck-8 > .card {
  flex-basis: calc(12.5% - 30px);
  max-width: calc(12.5% - 30px);
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-right: 15px; }

.deck-9 > .card {
  flex-basis: calc(11.1111111111% - 30px);
  max-width: calc(11.1111111111% - 30px);
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-right: 15px; }

.deck-10 > .card {
  flex-basis: calc(10% - 30px);
  max-width: calc(10% - 30px);
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-right: 15px; }

.deck-11 > .card {
  flex-basis: calc(9.0909090909% - 30px);
  max-width: calc(9.0909090909% - 30px);
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-right: 15px; }

.deck-12 > .card {
  flex-basis: calc(8.3333333333% - 30px);
  max-width: calc(8.3333333333% - 30px);
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-right: 15px; }

@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .deck-sm-1 > .card {
    flex-basis: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0; }

  .deck-sm-2 > .card {
    flex-basis: calc(50% - 30px);
    max-width: calc(50% - 30px);
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right: 15px; }

  .deck-sm-3 > .card {
    flex-basis: calc(33.3333333333% - 30px);
    max-width: calc(33.3333333333% - 30px);
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right: 15px; }

  .deck-sm-4 > .card {
    flex-basis: calc(25% - 30px);
    max-width: calc(25% - 30px);
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right: 15px; }

  .deck-sm-5 > .card {
    flex-basis: calc(20% - 30px);
    max-width: calc(20% - 30px);
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right: 15px; }

  .deck-sm-6 > .card {
    flex-basis: calc(16.6666666667% - 30px);
    max-width: calc(16.6666666667% - 30px);
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right: 15px; }

  .deck-sm-7 > .card {
    flex-basis: calc(14.2857142857% - 30px);
    max-width: calc(14.2857142857% - 30px);
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right: 15px; }

  .deck-sm-8 > .card {
    flex-basis: calc(12.5% - 30px);
    max-width: calc(12.5% - 30px);
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right: 15px; }

  .deck-sm-9 > .card {
    flex-basis: calc(11.1111111111% - 30px);
    max-width: calc(11.1111111111% - 30px);
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right: 15px; }

  .deck-sm-10 > .card {
    flex-basis: calc(10% - 30px);
    max-width: calc(10% - 30px);
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right: 15px; }

  .deck-sm-11 > .card {
    flex-basis: calc(9.0909090909% - 30px);
    max-width: calc(9.0909090909% - 30px);
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right: 15px; }

  .deck-sm-12 > .card {
    flex-basis: calc(8.3333333333% - 30px);
    max-width: calc(8.3333333333% - 30px);
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right: 15px; } }
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .deck-md-1 > .card {
    flex-basis: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0; }

  .deck-md-2 > .card {
    flex-basis: calc(50% - 30px);
    max-width: calc(50% - 30px);
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right: 15px; }

  .deck-md-3 > .card {
    flex-basis: calc(33.3333333333% - 30px);
    max-width: calc(33.3333333333% - 30px);
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right: 15px; }

  .deck-md-4 > .card {
    flex-basis: calc(25% - 30px);
    max-width: calc(25% - 30px);
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right: 15px; }

  .deck-md-5 > .card {
    flex-basis: calc(20% - 30px);
    max-width: calc(20% - 30px);
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right: 15px; }

  .deck-md-6 > .card {
    flex-basis: calc(16.6666666667% - 30px);
    max-width: calc(16.6666666667% - 30px);
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right: 15px; }

  .deck-md-7 > .card {
    flex-basis: calc(14.2857142857% - 30px);
    max-width: calc(14.2857142857% - 30px);
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right: 15px; }

  .deck-md-8 > .card {
    flex-basis: calc(12.5% - 30px);
    max-width: calc(12.5% - 30px);
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right: 15px; }

  .deck-md-9 > .card {
    flex-basis: calc(11.1111111111% - 30px);
    max-width: calc(11.1111111111% - 30px);
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right: 15px; }

  .deck-md-10 > .card {
    flex-basis: calc(10% - 30px);
    max-width: calc(10% - 30px);
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right: 15px; }

  .deck-md-11 > .card {
    flex-basis: calc(9.0909090909% - 30px);
    max-width: calc(9.0909090909% - 30px);
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right: 15px; }

  .deck-md-12 > .card {
    flex-basis: calc(8.3333333333% - 30px);
    max-width: calc(8.3333333333% - 30px);
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right: 15px; } }
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .deck-lg-1 > .card {
    flex-basis: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0; }

  .deck-lg-2 > .card {
    flex-basis: calc(50% - 30px);
    max-width: calc(50% - 30px);
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right: 15px; }

  .deck-lg-3 > .card {
    flex-basis: calc(33.3333333333% - 30px);
    max-width: calc(33.3333333333% - 30px);
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right: 15px; }

  .deck-lg-4 > .card {
    flex-basis: calc(25% - 30px);
    max-width: calc(25% - 30px);
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right: 15px; }

  .deck-lg-5 > .card {
    flex-basis: calc(20% - 30px);
    max-width: calc(20% - 30px);
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right: 15px; }

  .deck-lg-6 > .card {
    flex-basis: calc(16.6666666667% - 30px);
    max-width: calc(16.6666666667% - 30px);
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right: 15px; }

  .deck-lg-7 > .card {
    flex-basis: calc(14.2857142857% - 30px);
    max-width: calc(14.2857142857% - 30px);
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right: 15px; }

  .deck-lg-8 > .card {
    flex-basis: calc(12.5% - 30px);
    max-width: calc(12.5% - 30px);
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right: 15px; }

  .deck-lg-9 > .card {
    flex-basis: calc(11.1111111111% - 30px);
    max-width: calc(11.1111111111% - 30px);
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right: 15px; }

  .deck-lg-10 > .card {
    flex-basis: calc(10% - 30px);
    max-width: calc(10% - 30px);
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right: 15px; }

  .deck-lg-11 > .card {
    flex-basis: calc(9.0909090909% - 30px);
    max-width: calc(9.0909090909% - 30px);
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right: 15px; }

  .deck-lg-12 > .card {
    flex-basis: calc(8.3333333333% - 30px);
    max-width: calc(8.3333333333% - 30px);
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right: 15px; } }
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .deck-xl-1 > .card {
    flex-basis: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0; }

  .deck-xl-2 > .card {
    flex-basis: calc(50% - 30px);
    max-width: calc(50% - 30px);
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right: 15px; }

  .deck-xl-3 > .card {
    flex-basis: calc(33.3333333333% - 30px);
    max-width: calc(33.3333333333% - 30px);
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right: 15px; }

  .deck-xl-4 > .card {
    flex-basis: calc(25% - 30px);
    max-width: calc(25% - 30px);
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right: 15px; }

  .deck-xl-5 > .card {
    flex-basis: calc(20% - 30px);
    max-width: calc(20% - 30px);
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right: 15px; }

  .deck-xl-6 > .card {
    flex-basis: calc(16.6666666667% - 30px);
    max-width: calc(16.6666666667% - 30px);
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right: 15px; }

  .deck-xl-7 > .card {
    flex-basis: calc(14.2857142857% - 30px);
    max-width: calc(14.2857142857% - 30px);
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right: 15px; }

  .deck-xl-8 > .card {
    flex-basis: calc(12.5% - 30px);
    max-width: calc(12.5% - 30px);
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right: 15px; }

  .deck-xl-9 > .card {
    flex-basis: calc(11.1111111111% - 30px);
    max-width: calc(11.1111111111% - 30px);
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right: 15px; }

  .deck-xl-10 > .card {
    flex-basis: calc(10% - 30px);
    max-width: calc(10% - 30px);
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right: 15px; }

  .deck-xl-11 > .card {
    flex-basis: calc(9.0909090909% - 30px);
    max-width: calc(9.0909090909% - 30px);
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right: 15px; }

  .deck-xl-12 > .card {
    flex-basis: calc(8.3333333333% - 30px);
    max-width: calc(8.3333333333% - 30px);
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right: 15px; } }
```

Answer (score 1):

@Zim provided a great solution above (well deserved up-vote from me), however, it didn't quite fit what I needed since I was implementing this in Jekyll and wanted my card deck to automatically update every time I added a post to my site. Growing a card deck such as this with each new post is straight forward in Jekyll, the challenge was to correctly place the breakpoints. My solution make use of additional liquid tags and modulo mathematics.

While this question is old, I came across it and found it useful, and maybe someday someone will come along wanting to do this with Jekyll.

```
<div class = "container">
  <div class = "card-deck">

    {% for post in site.posts %}
      <div class = "card border-0 mt-2">
        <a href = "{{ post.url }}"><img src = "{{ site.baseurl }}{{ post.image }}" class = "mx-auto" alt = "..."></a>
        <div class = "card-body">
          <h5 class = "card-title"><a href = "{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a></h5>
          <span>Published: {{ post.date | date_to_long_string }} </span>
          <p class = "text-muted">{{ post.excerpt }}</p>
        </div>
        <div class = "card-footer bg-white border-0"><a href = "{{ post.url }}" class = "btn btn-primary">Read more</a></div>
      </div>

      <!-- Use modulo to add divs to handle break points -->
      {% assign sm = forloop.index | modulo: 2 %}
      {% assign md = forloop.index | modulo: 3 %}
      {% assign lg = forloop.index | modulo: 4 %}
      {% assign xl = forloop.index | modulo: 5 %}

      {% if sm == 0 %}
        <div class="w-100 d-none d-sm-block d-md-none"><!-- wrap every 2 on sm--></div>
      {% endif %}

      {% if md == 0 %}
        <div class="w-100 d-none d-md-block d-lg-none"><!-- wrap every 3 on md--></div>
      {% endif %}

      {% if lg == 0 %}
        <div class="w-100 d-none d-lg-block d-xl-none"><!-- wrap every 4 on lg--></div>
      {% endif %}

      {% if xl == 0 %}
        <div class="w-100 d-none d-xl-block"><!-- wrap every 5 on xl--></div>
      {% endif %}

    {% endfor %}
  </div>
</div>
```

This whole code block can be used directly in a website or saved in your Jekyll project `_includes` folder.

Answer (score -1):

There's simpler solution for that - **set fixed height of card elements** - header and body. This way, we can set resposive layout with standard boostrap column grid.

Here is my example:
http://codeply.com/go/RHDawRSBol

```
 <div class="card-deck text-center">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
        <div class="card mb-4">
            <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="//placehold.it/500x280" alt="Card image cap">
            <div class="card-body" style="height: 20rem">
                <h4 class="card-title">1 Card title</h4>
                <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: But this is not the standard way.

Comment: If you do it this way you would have to know how much content is in your cards at all times.  This doesn't work for dynamic content.

Answer (score -4):

It took me a bit to figure this out, but the answer is to not use a card-deck, but instead to use `.row` and `.col`s.

This makes a responsive set of cards with specifics for each screen size: 3 cards for `xl`, 2 for `lg` and `md`, and 1 for `sm` and `xs`.  `.my-3` puts a padding on top and bottom so they look nice.

```
mixin postList(stuff)
  .row
    - site.posts.each(function(post, index){
      .col-sm-12.col-md-6.col-lg-6.col-xl-4
        .card.my-3
          img.card-img-top(src="...",  alt="Card image cap")
          .card-body
            h5.card-title Card title #{index}
            p.card-text Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the cards content.
            a.btn.btn-primary(href="#") Go somewhere
    - })
```

Comment: This method doesn't set the height of the cards to equal heights like a card-deck does.