# Bootstrap Card to new line responsive

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, responsive-design

I'm currently working on a website for a friend and I'm using Bootstrap 4 alpha.

Using the Cards i have three cards shown on the page and I would like that when the screen becomes mobile size to change to one card per line:

I don't want to use column but i want to use [Bootstrap Cards](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/card/)

Example:

- Normal Screen

  ```
  +++ CARD 1 +++ +++ CARD 2 +++ +++ CARD 3 +++
  ```
- Mobile screen

  ```
  +++ CARD 1 +++

  +++ CARD 2 +++

  +++ CARD 3 +++
  ```

the website is: http://www.smitefr.mmo-stream.net/index.php

Example of code:

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="card">
            <img src="images/dieux/Agni.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
            <h1> Agni</h1>
            <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
        </div><div class="card">
            <img src="images/dieux/AhMuzenCab.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
            <h1> Ah Muzen Cab</h1>
            <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
        </div><div class="card">
            <img src="images/dieux/AhPuch.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
            <h1> Ah Puch</h1>
            <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
        </div>
</div>
```

Example of css:

```
.card {
    float: left;
    width: 33.333%;
    padding: .75rem;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
    border: 0;
}

.card > img {
    margin-bottom: .75rem;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    height: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.card-text {
    font-size: 85%;
}
```

Comment: you can use bootstrap grid .col-md-3 and col-sx-12 for mobile

Comment: @LalitBhakuni I want to use Cards

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
<!-- Columns start at full width on mobile and bump up to 33.3% wide on desktop -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm col-xs-12">One</div>
    <div class="col-sm col-xs-12">Two</div>
    <div class="col-sm col-xs-12">Three</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Updated** with the cards:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm col-xs-12">
      <div class="card">
        <img src="//placehold.it/100?text=Agni.jpg" alt="Card image cap" />
        <h1> Agni</h1>
        <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm col-xs-12">
      <div class="card">
        <img src="//placehold.it/100?text=AhMuzenCab.jpg" alt="Card image cap" />
        <h1> Ah Muzen Cab</h1>
        <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm col-xs-12">
      <div class="card">
        <img src="//placehold.it/100?text=AhPuch.jpg" alt="Card image cap" />
        <h1> Ah Puch</h1>
        <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Snippet**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm col-xs-12">
      <div class="card">
        <img src="//placehold.it/100?text=Agni.jpg" alt="Card image cap" />
        <h1> Agni</h1>
        <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm col-xs-12">
      <div class="card">
        <img src="//placehold.it/100?text=AhMuzenCab.jpg" alt="Card image cap" />
        <h1> Ah Muzen Cab</h1>
        <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm col-xs-12">
      <div class="card">
        <img src="//placehold.it/100?text=AhPuch.jpg" alt="Card image cap" />
        <h1> Ah Puch</h1>
        <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

See the responsive demo of above code in [**JSBin**](http://output.jsbin.com/nobagowedi).

**Preview**

Desktop View

[image: desktop]

Mobile View

[image: mobile]

Comment: The thing is i wanted to use the [bootstrap cards](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/card/) since they are very practical to display data

Comment: @Mederic See the responsive demo of above code in [**JSBin**](http://output.jsbin.com/nobagowedi). You can use any kind of content inside it.

Comment: I updated on the website but my cards get completely reduced cant even see the image anymore.

Comment: @Mederic Let me check. I just checked. Can you use `col-sm-4` instead of `col-sm`?

Comment: Looks nearly perfect but could you help me figure one thing out. On the website if i go near aphrodite at one point while i slowly resize to lower i get 3 column very small and the <h1> [goes out of the card](https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2017/16/1492766819-resize.png)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142265/discussion-between-praveen-kumar-and-mederic).

Comment: @Mederic You need to do it for `-sm-` class then... Instead of using `col-sm-4 col-xs-12`, try `col-md-4 col-sm-12`

Comment: That works fine thanks a lot for the quick answer. If you have anymore suggestions don't hesitate.

Answer (score 0):

After several hours of exploration, the below worked for me.

If you want a responsive card-deck, use the visibility utils to force a wrap every X columns on different viewport width(breakpoints)...

[Bootstrap 4 responsive card-deck (v 4.1)](https://www.codeply.com/go/nIB6oSbv6q)

More details available in the below link.

[Bootstrap 4 card-deck with number of columns based on viewport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36430816/bootstrap-4-card-deck-with-number-of-columns-based-on-viewport)