# How make Bootstrap 4 card decks same width each row?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am displaying 4 cards each row using a card deck:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="card-deck">
    <!-- 4 of these -->
    <div class="card">
      <img class="card-img-top img-adjusted" >
       <div class="card-body">...</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="card-deck">
    <!-- 4 of these -->
    <div class="card">
      <img class="card-img-top img-adjusted" >
       <div class="card-body">...</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
...
```

The cards within each deck are the same width, but the **decks** are not, i.e. the deck of the 2nd row is wider than the deck of the 1st row. How do I get the decks to be of the same width?

I have tried setting `.card-decks{width: 100%;}`, which works for full rows, but distorts cards of rows that have just 1-2 cards.

Additional CSS:
My images are of different sizes, that's why I added the following CSS to make them the same. No other CSS should affect the cards:

```
.img-adjusted{
position: relative;
float: left;
background-position: 50% 50%;
background-repeat:   no-repeat;
background-size:     cover;
}
```

Also, I want to keep the style responsive, so would like to avoid hardcoding pixel set pixel widths.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Don't put `.card-deck` in a `.row`. **Only `.col-` columns should be placed in rows.**..

> content must be placed within columns and only columns may be
>   immediate children of rows.

You should use...

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-12">
  <div class="card-deck">
    <!-- 4 of these -->
    <div class="card">
      <img class="card-img-top img-adjusted" >
       <div class="card-body">...</div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

The 2nd part of the question...

When using `card-deck` (and `card-group`), cards will always fill the width of the next visual row. If you have less than 4 cards in each row, the remaining cards will fill the width across. To workaround this, set a max-width for each card..

```
.card-deck .card {
    max-width: calc(25% - 30px);
}
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/ygvZvjsELs

Alternatively, You can use the grid columns to wrap the cards. This is explained here: [Bootstrap 4 card-deck with number of columns based on viewport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36430816/bootstrap-4-card-deck-with-number-of-columns-based-on-viewport)

Comment: Ok, this works for full rows, but seems to have the same effect like `width: 100%;`, as in if the deck only has a single card it will be distorted. I guess, my question should then be about how to deal with card decks with less number of cards? (I generate the rows dynamically, the last row will not always have 4 cards)

Comment: why is it `-30px`?

Comment: Because padding is given in left and right 15 px , 15 px. So