# Bootstrap b-card in b-card

Tags: css, vue.js, bootstrap-4, vue-component, bootstrap-vue

I've case on Card class bootstrap,
Here I want to make 1 parent card and 4 child card (in parent card) and make them 6 column every 1 child card, but when I make 4 child card with col-xl-6 then the other child card make new line. I want to make the child card using grid bootstrap column. Here my code

template

```
<b-card class="card-congratulation-medal bg-rts-main row">
  <h5 class="text-white col-xl-12">
    Selamat Siang,<br>
    {{ user.nama }} ({{user.kode}})
  </h5>
  <b-card class="p-0 col-xl-3 col-md-3 mt-2" v-for="(item, index) in cardItem" :key="index">
    <h5>{{ item.title }}</h5>
  </b-card>
</b-card>
```

data()

```
cardItem: [
  {
    title: "Point",
    icon: "asem"
  },
  {
    title: "Invoice Unpaid",
    icon: "asem"
  },
  {
    title: "Resi",
    icon: "asem"
  },
  {
    title: "Goods",
    icon: "asem"
  },
]
```

the result of my case here :
[My Case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uo1Ge.png)

I want to make like that, 6 column every .card :
[My expetation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/11gAP.png)

My element :
[image]

Comment: Can you draw and explain the desired output? I am not able to understand the question

Comment: Hi, Thank you. Here is my expectation : https://i.stack.imgur.com/11gAP.png

Comment: @Wilson here is my trouble : https://i.stack.imgur.com/uo1Ge.png .
I want the result is like my expectation

Comment: col-md-6 col-xl-6 col-sm-6... you have to use. then only you will get the desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the `v-for` in `<b-row>`:

```html
<b-card class="card-congratulation-medal bg-rts-main row">
  <h5 class="text-white col-xl-12">
    Selamat Siang,<br>
    {{ user.nama }} ({{user.kode}})
  </h5>

  <b-row cols="2">
    <b-col v-for="(item, index) in cardItem" :key="index">
      <b-card class="p-0 mt-2">
        <h5>{{ item.title }}</h5>
      </b-card>
    </b-col>
  </b-row>

</b-card>
```

Here is a [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-roentgen-2mozj)

---

*From comments:*  When importing plugins instead of the whole library, make sure to import the `LayoutPlugin` (for `<b-row>` and `<b-col>`) and `CardPlugin` for `<b-card>`:

```js
import { LayoutPlugin, CardPlugin } from 'bootstrap-vue'

Vue.use(LayoutPlugin);
Vue.use(CardPlugin);
```

Comment: I also though it would work, I've tried your code with copy paste, but the result of your code : https://imgur.com/a/NDG9YJ2

Comment: Here is a demo of this code working:  https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-roentgen-2mozj

Comment: that working on demo, but I don't know why on my code is didn't work.
I think the peru (#d98050) color that's the problem : https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vhd9V.png

Comment: is there any other css trick that can solve this peru color area ?

Comment: Can you show how you've installed Bootstrap Vue?

Comment: "bootstrap": "4.5.2",
    "bootstrap-vue": "2.21.1",

Comment: my ```main.js``` : https://www.protectedtext.com/problem123
password : 123

Comment: You need to `import`/`use` the `LayoutPlugin` and `CardPlugin`.  You should import all of `BootstrapVue` until you are ready for production and understand the library.

Answer (score 1):

You do it like this in bootstrap.

[How make Bootstrap 4 card decks same width each row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49095075/how-make-bootstrap-4-card-decks-same-width-each-row)

---

You need to use the `.card` in a `.col-xl-6` which is a descendant of a `.row`.

```
  <b-row>
    <b-col class="col-xl-6" v-for="(item, index) in cardItem" :key="index">
      <b-card class="p-0 mt-2" >
        <h5>{{ item.title }}</h5>
      </b-card>
    </b-col>
  </b-row>
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/1w8tf

---