# bootstrap col-md-4 doesn't stay 33% width always

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm working with bootstrap cards. The amount of cards within a card-deck is dynamic. Now my issue is that each card should be `col-md-4` (33%) in width. When the amount of cards is > 1 everything is fine, but as soon as I only have a single card this card is not 33% based on `col-md-4`.

Here a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2o09b4te/
remove cards 1 by 1 until you have 1 left.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

3 cards: result correct
[image: 3 cards: result correct]

2 cards: result correct
[image: 2 cards: result correct]

1 card: result wrong
[image: 1 card: result wrong]

Comment: `<div class="card-deck my-3 text-center"> ` the problemi is with this div

Comment: Columns should always be direct descendant of `.row`. Why are you using the `.card-deck`? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36430816/bootstrap-4-card-deck-with-number-of-columns-based-on-viewport/36431664#36431664

Comment: @Zim Why is a good question. When I saw those cards I thought they look great and fit perfectly for my use case. In the example they built a card-deck out of cards. So I did this as well. Can't give you anything more then that why I used this. Removing card-deck seems to solve my issue.

Comment: Basically "Need a set of equal width and height cards that aren’t attached to one another? Use card decks." is exactly what I wanted at least optic wise. By removing card-deck I have the same looks based on col-md's padding. So I think I should be fine with it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.row` must contain direcly `.col-...`.

Here is a correction :
https://jsfiddle.net/8mhbz9gj/1/

Comment: From what I see you removed `<div class="card-deck my-3 text-center">` then it works for me as well.

Comment: Yes, I also added a `<div class="container-fluid">` to have a nicer demo. I also moved `.text-center` and change `.my-3` to `.py-3` on the `.row`.

Comment: AFter a break on the weekend I reread your answer and finally got what you said. I was confused because what you did in your jsfiddle didn't matched your answer in my world. Anyway, thank you sir ;)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `<div>` tag which follows `<div>` tag with class row, contain class name col-md-4.

on your first card, swap

```
 <div class="card-deck my-3 text-center">
  <div class="col-md-4">
```

Like this

```
<div class="col-md-4">
<div class="card-deck my-3 text-center">
```

Comment: this doesn't work for me since the card-deck contains multiple cards.