# Bootstrap 4 card deck table-cell columns responsive based on viewport?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-4, bootstrap-4

So in Bootstrap v4, I see there's a new feature for card decks ( http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/card/#decks ) that makes a group of cards, with their height equal according to the tallest content in the group.

It appears the number of columns are based on how many card-div's are in the group. Is there a way to make the number of columns change based on the viewport? For example, 4 columns / card wide at large width, 2 wide at medium width, and 1 at small width?

Currently they stay the same number of columns/cards wide until less than 544px. At 544px and greater, they have `display: table-cell` with the `screen (min-width: 544px)` rule.

Is there a way to make the cards have different numbers of columns based on viewport by changing only the CSS?

**Edit -** Looking to not use flex / flexbox due to IE support

Codepen example of 4 col/card wide and 3 col/card wide at http://codepen.io/jpost-vlocity/full/PNEKKy/

Answer (score 35):

I found a pretty easy workaround using css-grid. You could tweak the 250px to fit your use case.

```
.card-deck {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(250px, 1fr));
    grid-gap: .5rem;
}
```

Comment: Used this to display an unlimited amount of Cards properly, works much better than reactstrap CardDesk for instance. Awesome. :)

Comment: For my case I use auto-fill instead of auto-fit as the number of cards varies from 1 to 100 and if card count is below 5, gap between cards get increase to fit inside the parent div.

Comment: Very elegant aproach

Answer (score 15):

**Update 2019**

It's hard to set the cards widths (responsive) with `card-deck` because it uses `display:table-cell` and `width:1%`.

I found it easier to make them responsive using the cards inside the Bootstap grid `col-*` and then you can use the grid viewport breakpoints. Enable Bootstrap's flexbox if you want the cards to be equal height like the `card-deck`.

http://www.codeply.com/go/6eqGPn3Qud

Also, `img-responsive` has changed to `img-fluid`

## Bootstrap 4.0.0

**Flexbox is now the default**, but there is still not a *supported* way to make responsive card-deck's. The recommended way is to use cards inside the grid:

[Responsive cards using grid](http://www.codeply.com/go/AeCiHRF7gx)

Another way to make a responsive card-deck, is using responsive reset divs every *x* columns. This will force cards to wrap at specific breakpoints.

For example: 5 on xl, 4 on lg, 3 on md, 2 on sm, etc..

[Responsive card deck demo (**4.0.0**)](https://www.codeply.com/go/k2zBsujRhJ)
[Responsive card deck demo (alpha 6)](http://www.codeply.com/go/nIB6oSbv6q/responsive-card-deck)
[CSS pseudo elements variation](http://www.codeply.com/go/Zu7Cc9CD9Y)

Comment: Is there a way to do it without flex / flexbox? For IE support of course

Comment: The link to the responsive cards using grid doesn't quite work. It assumes equal text length, and that the heading length is the same for all cards. If you add a little more text - it falls flat. Good try tho.

Comment: @WindUpLordVexxos it works fine. If your concern is equal height cards just use `h-100` on the cards. http://www.codeply.com/go/AeCiHRF7gx

Answer (score 6):

Simply drop `h-100` class on cards in grid.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6 my-3">
    <div class="card h-100">
      <!-- full height -->
      <div class="card-header">Header 1</div>
      <div class="card-body">Body 1</div>
      <div class="card-footer">Footer 1</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6 my-3">
    <div class="card h-100">
      <!-- full height -->
      <div class="card-header">Header 2</div>
      <div class="card-body">Body 2 <br> 2a <br> 2b <br> 2c</div>
      <div class="card-footer">Footer 2</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6 my-3">
    <div class="card h-100">
      <!-- full height -->
      <div class="card-header">Header 3 <br> 3a</div>
      <div class="card-body">Body 3</div>
      <div class="card-footer">Footer 3 <br> 3a </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6 my-3">
    <div class="card h-100">
      <!-- full height -->
      <div class="card-header">Header 2</div>
      <div class="card-body">Body 2 <br> 2a <br> 2b <br> 2c</div>
      <div class="card-footer">Footer 2</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is key! Get rid of card-deck class, replace with row. Add h-100 to card class. Be sure to add a "mb-3" or more class to card as well so there is some spacing. This will break on any assigned viewport. :D

Answer (score 4):

Here you go, 
http://codepen.io/KarlDoyle/pen/pypWbR

The main thing is that you have to override the styles. as shown below.

```
.card-deck {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-flow: row wrap; 
  align-items: stretch;
}
.card-deck .card {
  display: block;
  flex-basis: 33.3%; /* change this value for each breakpoint*/
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it without flex / flexbox? For IE support of course

Comment: @jpostdesign - you could use a polyfill https://github.com/10up/flexibility or you could create your own component which is not dependent on flex and using floats instead. 

Also check out this fallback solution which may be of help https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/flexbox-with-fallback/

Comment: Just a point though, Bootstrap & Flexbox - regarding support for IE http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/flexbox/

Answer (score 3):

### Bootstrap 4 card deck responsive

I tried to use the `<container>`, `<row>` and `<col>` to make it responsive, but you lose the

> All the cards have the same height

feature of the card deck, if you do that.
What you need is CSS:

```
.card-deck {
  margin: 0 -15px;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.card-deck .card {
  margin: 0 0 1rem;
}

@media (min-width: 576px) and (max-width: 767.98px) {
  .card-deck .card {
    -ms-flex: 0 0 48.7%;
    flex: 0 0 48.7%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991.98px) {
  .card-deck .card {
    -ms-flex: 0 0 32%;
    flex: 0 0 32%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px)
{
  .card-deck .card {
    -ms-flex: 0 0 24%;
    flex: 0 0 24%;
  }
}
```

Here is my CodePen:
[Bootstrap 4 card deck responsive](https://codepen.io/FrankieDoodie/pen/OoVXvp)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="card-deck">
        <div class="card my-3">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/560x560" class="card-img-top">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">Title</h4>
                <p class="card-text">Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Button</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card my-3">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/560x560" class="card-img-top">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">Title</h4>
                <p class="card-text">Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Button</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card my-3">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/560x560" class="card-img-top">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">Title</h4>
                <p class="card-text">Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Button</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card my-3">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/560x560" class="card-img-top">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">Title</h4>
                <p class="card-text">Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Button</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
// Bootstrap 4 breakpoints & gutter
$grid-breakpoints: (
    xs: 0,
    sm: 576px,
    md: 768px,
    lg: 992px,
    xl: 1200px
) !default;

$grid-gutter-width: 30px !default;

// number of cards per line for each breakpoint
$cards-per-line: (
    xs: 1,
    sm: 2,
    md: 3,
    lg: 4,
    xl: 5
);

@each $name, $breakpoint in $grid-breakpoints {
    @media (min-width: $breakpoint) {
        .card-deck .card {
            flex: 0 0 calc(#{100/map-get($cards-per-line, $name)}% - #{$grid-gutter-width});
        }
    }
}
```

Demo on codepen [Bootstrap 4 responsive card-deck](https://codepen.io/ayoubkhan558/pen/RwwPxvJ)