# Bootstrap 4 (Alpha 3): card columns - customized number of columns

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-4, bootstrap-4

I use in Bootstrap 4 (Alpha 3) Card Colums and try to customize the number of colums. There is the following example in the [Docs](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/card/#columns):

```
.card-columns {
      @include media-breakpoint-only(lg) {
        column-count: 4;
      }
      @include media-breakpoint-only(xl) {
        column-count: 5;
      }
    }
```

As the default column-count is 3 (except for sm devices), I try to reduce the default to 2 columns, using the following code in an additional CSS file (after Bootstrap CSS):

```
.card-columns {
  @include media-breakpoint-only(sm) {
    column-count: 2;
  }
  @include media-breakpoint-only(md) {
    column-count: 2;
  }
  @include media-breakpoint-only(lg) {
    column-count: 2;
  }
  @include media-breakpoint-only(xl) {
    column-count: 2;
  }
}
```

But, unfortunately, the result is still 3 columns. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: With SASS enabled it works: http://codeply.com/go/nHZg5n2vuE

Comment: Thank you. No I need to find out how to enable SASS ... (the related docs [http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/best-practices/] seems not to be ready yet).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap 4 - Responsive cards in card-columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34140793/bootstrap-4-responsive-cards-in-card-columns)

Answer (score 4):

You need to use the `@media` CSS tag. Use the CSS code below in the site's CSS file and you should be good to go.

```
@media (min-width: 576px) and (max-width: 768px)
{
    .card-columns {
        -webkit-column-count: 2;
        -moz-column-count: 2;
        column-count: 2;
    }
}
```

The "column-count" properties is all you need to change.

You can change the `min-width` and `max-width` to any of bootstraps grid options to get the desired results. See [Bootstraps Grid Options](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/#grid-options) for referance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SASS to change the `media-breakpoint-only`..

```
.card-columns {
  @include media-breakpoint-only(xl) {
    column-count: 5;
  }
  @include media-breakpoint-only(lg) {
    column-count: 4;
  }
  @include media-breakpoint-only(md) {
    column-count: 3;
  }
  @include media-breakpoint-only(sm) {
    column-count: 2;
  }
}
```

Working demo: http://codeply.com/go/nHZg5n2vuE

Comment: could you add what this would be without SASS

Comment: See this Q/A https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34140793/bootstrap-4-responsive-cards-in-card-columns/43117538#43117538