# Google Map is not working with bootstrap card layout in Chrome

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-4

I'm using bootstrap card layout with google map. But whenever I move google map to a card in a right column it doesn't display properly. But if I moved it to first column it works! This issue only happens in chrome and edge. Works perfectly in firefox. Any ideas to solve this issue?

View following code in full screen

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="card-columns">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-body">
            <p class="card-text">This is a longer card</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card"> <!-- If I move this card to top, so it  will be on left side. Then it works!!!-->
          <div class="card-body">
            <div id="googleMap" style="width:100%;height:400px;"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <script>
        function myMap() {
          var mapProp = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742, -0.120850),
            zoom: 5,
          };
          var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);
        }
      </script>
      <script
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDvPRM33ZqqUlIdR-g3kT8gLj_cWWD4HHk&callback=myMap"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**Check the comment in the second card**

This is how it looks in chrome and edge!

[image]

**Edit**

I find out that this is a problem related to css column-count. With this google maps are not properly rendering.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `card-deck` or `card-group`
Then it works.
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/card/

Or have a look at the column-count workaround for card-columns
[Bootstrap 4 - Responsive cards in card-columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34140793/bootstrap-4-responsive-cards-in-card-columns)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    
    <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
      <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDvPRM33ZqqUlIdR-g3kT8gLj_cWWD4HHk&callback=myMap" defer></script>
      <script defer>
        function myMap() {
          var mapProp = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742, -0.120850),
            zoom: 5,
          };
          var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);
        }
      </script>
    </head>
    
    <body>
      <div class="container mt-5">
        <div class="card-deck">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
              <p class="card-text">This is a longer card</p>
    
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="card">
            <!-- If I move this card to top, so it  will be on left side. Then it works!!!-->
            <div class="card-body">
              <p class="card-text">This is a longer card</p>
              <div id="googleMap" style="width:100%;height:400px;"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

Comment: In my original application it has few more cards with different heights. So card-deck and group won't work :(

Comment: I'll have a look at it again soon

Comment: Thanks, Actually this is a problem with css column-count property. Bootstrap cards using it.

Comment: @SameeraK have a look at this, to fix your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34140793/bootstrap-4-responsive-cards-in-card-columns